# Sci-kit Learn Linear Regression with multiple feature

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was working with Sci-kit Learn for linear regresion problem. In Sci-kit Learn website there is an example for one feature

```
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()


# Use only one feature
diabetes_X = diabetes.data[:, np.newaxis, 2]
```

I tried to change code little bit.

```
diabetes_X = diabetes.data[:, np.newaxis, [0,1,2]]
```

When i printed out this variable i've got something like this:

**[[ 0.03807591  0.05068012  0.06169621]] etc.**

So i can say that i've got 3 features right now. If i try to fit this training data to my model i've got this error:

```
regr.fit(diabetes_X_train, diabetes_y_train)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 427, in fit
    y_numeric=True, multi_output=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 510, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 396, in check_array
    % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

I've found only one feature examples on google so i don't how to train my model with multiple feature. Should i create a multiple variable and fit each feature to each variable? I hope i told my problem clearly.

Comment: and did you train to actually see what is the size of `diabetes_X` now? `print diabetes_X.shape`

Comment: Can you include more code so we can see what you are doing between these steps? Ideally a minimal working example would be nice.